Using xargs to map keys to values
In the code below I'm trying to replicate with xargs what works using while, but fell short. Any suggestion?
declare -A myassoc
myassoc['a']='foo'
myassoc['b']='bar'
myassoc['c']='baz'

keys=('a' 'b' 'c')

# output as expected
printf '%s\n' "${keys[@]}" | while read key; do echo -n ${myassoc[$key]}; done 
foobarbaz

# fail
printf '%s\n' "${keys[@]}" | xargs -I {} "$SHELL" -c 'echo -n ${myassoc[$1]}' _ {}

# debug
printf '%s\n' "${keys[@]}" | xargs -I {} "$SHELL" -c 'echo -n \${myassoc[$1]}' _ {}
${myassoc[a]}${myassoc[b]}${myassoc[c]}


You can't export an associative array, so a shell started by xargs won't have access to that array.
Here, what you can do is pass both keys and values. Unfortunately bash has copied the associative array design of ksh93 instead of that of zsh, so it makes it very awkward there.
If switching to zsh is an option, you can do:
typeset -A myassoc=(
  a foo
  b bar
  c baz
)

print -rNC1 -- "${(kv@)assoc}" | xargs -r0n2 sh -c '
  key=$1 value=$2
  printf "%s\n" "key=$key value=$value"' sh

To pass keys and values of the assoc (assuming keys and values don't contain NULs which zsh, contrary to bash allows) to xargs, raw and NUL delimited.
Not sure why you'd want to do something like that though.
To do the equivalent in ksh93/bash, you'd need a loop as you can't dump keys and values in one go there:
for key in "${!assoc[@]}"; do
  printf '%s\0' "$key" "${assoc[$key]}"
done | xargs -r0n2 sh -c '
  key=$1 value=$2
  printf "%s\n" "key=$key value=$value"' sh

In any case, if it's really just upon printing all the values of the assoc without separator nor line delimiter, then it's just:
printf %s $assoc        # zsh

printf %s "${assoc[@]}" # ksh93/bash

Bearing in mind that associate array elements have no defined order.
Some extra notes about your approach:

Unless you use -0 or GNU's -d option, xargs expect the input in a very specific format, even with -I, so can't be used for arbitrary key values. -0 (or -d '\0') can be used for associative array keys of bash and ksh93 as those have that limitation that they can't contain NULs¹
As usual, echo can't be used for arbitrary data. Use printf instead.
In sh 'some sh code' foo bar, foo goes into $0. That's used to give a name to your inline script. That name is displayed for instance in error message. So you shouldn't use things like _ there.
The syntax to read a line with read is IFS= read -r line, not read line, but in any case, it's not a line you want to read here, but a key of your associative array and in bash (or all shells that support associative arrays), keys can be made of several lines.
in bash (contrary to zsh), parameter expansions must be quoted or otherwise they under IFS-splitting and even globbing! You quoted $SHELL but not the other parameter expansions.


¹ bash's have that extra limitation that keys can't be empty.

"In any case, if it's really just upon printing all the values of the assoc without separator nor line delimiter," The  challenge rather, is keys in a specified order. The conclusion I draw from your answer is that while read remains the portable/robust way to go.

@Erwann, I don't see the point in using a while read loop (even after applying all the fixes I mention). Why not just for key in "${!assoc[@]}"; do something with "${assoc[$key]}"; done in bash or for key in "${(k@)assoc}"; do something with "$assoc[$key]"; done in zsh (or for key value ("${(kv@)assoc}") something with "$value")? In any case, assoc elements are not ordered.

"Why not just for key in "${!assoc[@]}?" For the reason I just said: "keys in a specified order", with the implication that in general it would be different from that of ${!assoc[@]}.

while or for, for that matter, but not xargs, is what I meant.
